# How to create cookies manually in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies

Yo, guys do you know how to create cookies for IE manually? I mean create programmatically a cookie from scratch with custom domain, expiration time, path and token value.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean a cookie like this:

```
var date = new Date();
var days = 10000;
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
document.cookie = "test" + "; expires= " + date.toGMTString(); +"; path=/";
alert(document.cookie);
```

Comment: This worked flawlessly; I was able to enter this code in the console of Internet Explorer (on Windows Server 2016), which adds a custom cookie with parameters (by adding more ; key=value; after the last mentioned '; path=/'). This post should be marked as the answer, surely!

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are usually created on a server using apis such as :[javax.servlet.http.Cookie](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html)
. That API allows you to specify the items you're asking about. The browser merely stashes the cookie it receives from the server.

The specific contents of a cookie are entirely application specific and are quite likely encrypted so that you cannot synthesise one without access to that particular server's infrastructure.

You can use javascript in the browser to manipulate cookies as described [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html), but unless you know what the server is expecting this does you little good.

Comment: Downvote? Please say why, then we can all learn.

Comment: Just be cool. No downvote there anymore... :D